# Adding a custom Field on customer registration Magento 1.7.2

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, paypal, register

Iam Using magrnto 1.7.2
I need to add a paypal email adress to customer registration form and need to validate it with paypal
Will anybody help me to achevie it?

Comment: Have you tried to Google? There are lots of articles on this subject.

Comment: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6

Comment: @Tim the tutorial is not working with 1.7.0.2

Comment: @MohammadFaisal i tried this tutorial but results Fatal error: Call to a member function select() on a non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\customer\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php on line 734.. can you please help me

Comment: @SamuelJMathew: have you been able to find the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the code in installer script to add column

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$cust_setup = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_setup', 'core_setup');
$cust_setup->addAttribute('customer', 'customer_code', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Customer Code',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 1,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'default' => '',
    'visible_on_front' => 1,
    'forms' => array(
        'customer_account_edit', 'customer_account_create', 'checkout_register', 'adminhtml_customer'
    )
));
Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
        ->getAttribute('customer', 'customer_code')
        ->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register'))
        ->save();
$tableQuote = $this->getTable('sales/quote');

$installer->run(
        "ALTER TABLE $tableQuote ADD `customer_customer_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL"
);
$installer->endSetup();
```

This is all you need to have to add column in magento database. For frontend display you may need to change the templates using layout xml of your module.

The code may look like:

```
<customer_account_create>
    <reference name="customer_form_register">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>sublogin/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>

<customer_account_login>
    <reference name="customer_form_login">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>sublogin/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account_login>
```

where in your template just add the input field for your column.